# Why am i getting an empty value from my doInBackground when using AsyncTask in an IntentService class?

Tags: android, android-asynctask, intentservice

I am trying to insert some points into a table in a database. For this i am using an `IntentService`, but i am getting an empty value from `onPostExecute`(i checked using debug). I am in doubt whether this is a good way to achieve this?- The problem is i can not find out why the value returned is empty?-Any help is very appreciated. Thanks, Carl.
Here is my class who extends `IntetService`:

```
public class ExampleClass extends IntentService {

    final String file = "text.txt";
    final File path = Environment.getExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Environment.DIRECTORY_DOCUMENTS);
    HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();

    public ExampleClass() {super("ExampleClass");}

    protected String ReadFile() {
        File file = new File(path, file);
        String line = "";
        StringBuilder text = new StringBuilder();
        try {
            BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new FileReader(file));
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                text.append(line + '\n');
            }
            br.close();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.getMessage()
        }
        return text.toString();
    }
    @Override
    protected void onHandleIntent(Intent intent) {
            String[] points = ReadFile().replace("\n", ",").split(",");
            List<String> latitude = new ArrayList<>(); 
            List<String> longitude = new ArrayList<>(); 
            for (int i = 0; i < points.length; i++) {
                if (i % 2 == 0) {
                    latitude.add(points[i]);
                } else {
                    longitude.add(points[i]); 
                }
            }
            List<Koordinate> koord = new ArrayList<>();
            for (int i = 0; i < latitude.size() && i < longitude.size(); i++) {
                Koordinate koordinate = new Koordinate(latitude.get(i), longitude.get(i));
                koord.add(koordinate);
            }
            Gson gson = new Gson();
            String json = gson.toJson(koordArray);  
            List<NameValuePair> nameValuePairs = new ArrayList<>(1);
            nameValuePairs.add(new BasicNameValuePair("toJson", json));
            new AsyncTask(this).execute(new Pair<>(nameValuePairs, httpClient));
    }
}
```

My `AsyncTask` class:

```
public class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask<Pair<List<NameValuePair>, HttpClient>, Void, String> {

    private Context context = null;

    public AsyncTaskTilPos(Context context) {this.context = context;}

    @Override
    protected String doInBackground(Pair<List<NameValuePair>, HttpClient>... params) {

        Pair pair = params[0];
        List<NameValuePair> urlParams = (List<NameValuePair>) pair.first;
        HttpClient httpClient = (HttpClient) pair.second;
        try {
            String serverURL = MainActivity.address + MainActivity.stringCommands
                    [MainActivity.TO_TABLE];
            HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(serverURL);
            httpPost.setEntity(new UrlEncodedFormEntity(urlParams));
            HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost);
            if (response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() == 200) {
                return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());
            }
            return "Wrong: " + response.getStatusLine().getStatusCode() + " " + response.getStatusLine().getReasonPhrase();
        } catch (ClientProtocolException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        } catch (IOException e) {
            return e.getMessage();
        }
    }
    @Override
    protected void onPostExecute(String result) {
        Intent i = new Intent("fileToTable").putExtra("theResultOfSendingFileToTable", result);
        LocalBroadcastManager.getInstance(context).sendBroadcast(i);
    }
}
```

and my `Servlet` class:

```
public class Servlet extends HttpServlet {

    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    public final static String NOT_LOGGED_IN = "You're not logged in";

    public SendingTilPosServlet() {super();}

    @Override
    public void doGet(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response)
            throws ServletException, IOException
    {
        handleRequest(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse
            response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        handleRequest(request, response);
    }

    private void handleRequest(HttpServletRequest req, HttpServletResponse
            resp) throws ServletException, IOException {

        String message = "";
        PrintWriter out = resp.getWriter();
        resp.setContentType("text/plain");
        resp.setContentLength(message.length());
        HttpSession session = req.getSession();
        String loggedIn = (String)session.getAttribute("logIn");
        try {
            if (loggedIn != null || loggedIn.equalsIgnoreCase("User is logged in")) {
                Gson gson = new Gson();
                String koordinates = req.getParameter("toJson");
                List<Koordinate> arrayKoord = gson.fromJson(koordinates, new TypeToken<ArrayList<Koordinate>>(){}.getType());
                DataBase dbh = new DataBase();
                boolean result = dbh.insertValuesToTable(arrayKoord);
                if(result) {
                    message = "Storage is successful";
                } else {
                    message = "Storage is unsuccessful";
                }
                out.println(message);
            } else {
                message = "You're not logged in";
                out.println(message);
            }
        } catch (NullPointerException e) {
            e.getMessage();
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: `public class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask`. Terrible. That it even is allowed. The constructor that takes a context parameter has a different name.

Comment: Do you get empty response from the server on successful request? That seems to be only branch in your code which could end up to such scenario. Also in your servlet, you set the content length to zero always. That might affect the outcome too.

Comment: This is another problem! i don't know if the empty response is coming from the server?- i tried to debug the 'Servlet' but it dosen't stop where i put the breakPoints!

Comment: @greenapps `public class AsyncTask extends AsyncTask.` this is a forgetful. `public class MyAsyncTask extends AsyncTask.` should be

Answer (score 2, accepted):

below code must run on main thread not on worker thread(onHandleIntent)

```
new AsyncTask(this).execute(new Pair<>(nameValuePairs, httpClient));
```

simply remove that and copy and past all of `doInBackground`and `onPostExecute` code instead of it or if you want to create another thread inside worker thread use thread class.

Comment: I tried this and i get multiple errors. Example under `return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());` am getting: `Cannot return a value from a method with void result type`. Can i make `onHandleIntent` return a `String`?

Comment: No, I actually you can not, simply replace `return EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());` by `result = EntityUtils.toString(response.getEntity());` and use the result. It is a simple block of code like you code inside a function.

Comment: I will not nag. it's my first time with `IntentService`!. One more and last question: I changed the `context` (in `onPostExecute`) to `getApplicationContext()` is it ok?- and i don't understand how to change `params`(the parameters of the task) from `Pair pair = params[0]`?

Comment: "is it ok?" I think so but if it is not working pass `this` as context. So instead of `Pair pair = params[0];` use `Pair pair = new Pair<>(nameValuePairs, httpClient);` I use the argument you pass the `asynctask` inside `.execute`

Comment: Many thanks for your help. I have understood much better